# detached entity passed to persist problem

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have been starting to learn Spring-boot and have a problem in Create an object in MySQL,
when I run It is failed and I don't know why
it said that because of detached entity passed to persist problem and

trying spring boot, in the video said, that the bean for entityManager spring creates automatically, and in the video guy having problems. but in my case I have an error Could not autowire. No beans of the 'EntityManager' type were found.

It is my code

```
package com.example.cruddemo.dao;

import com.example.cruddemo.entity.student;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO{

    //define field for entity manager

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    //inject entity manager using constructor
    @Autowired
    public StudentDAOImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    //implement save method
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(student theStudent) {
        //save student to the database
        entityManager.persist(theStudent);
    }

}
It is Main:

package com.example.cruddemo;

import com.example.cruddemo.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.example.cruddemo.entity.student;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CruddemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CruddemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
      public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(StudentDAO studentDAO){
        return runner -> {
            createStudent(studentDAO);
        };
    }
    private void createStudent(@NotNull StudentDAO studentDAO){

        //create the student object
        System.out.println("Creating new student object...");
        student tempStudent = new student("taha","ahmadi","taha@ahmadi");
        tempStudent.setId(1);

        //save student object
        System.out.println("Saving Student Object...");
        studentDAO.save(tempStudent);

        //display id for saver student
        System.out.println("Saved student. Generated id:" + tempStudent.getId());
    }
}
and It is error


"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=54459:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Taha\Desktop\Programming Language\Java-Learning\springboot\dev-spring-boot\00-starter-sql-scripts\01-cruddemo-student\target\classes;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.0.8\spring-aop-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.19\aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.0.1\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.0.8\spring-jdbc-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.1.7.Final\hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.6.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.23\byte-buddy-1.12.23.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.2\jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.2\jaxb-core-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.0\angus-activation-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.2\txw2-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.1\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.0\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.10.1\antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.0.5\spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.0.5\spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.0.8\spring-orm-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.0.8\spring-context-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.0.8\spring-expression-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.0.8\spring-tx-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.0.8\spring-beans-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.7\slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.0.8\spring-aspects-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\com\mysql\mysql-connector-j\8.0.33\mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.0.6\spring-boot-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.0.6\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.7\logback-classic-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.7\logback-core-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.19.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.19.0\log4j-api-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.7\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.7.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.33\snakeyaml-1.33.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.0\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.0.8\spring-core-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.0.8\spring-jcl-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Taha\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\annotations\24.0.1\annotations-24.0.1.jar" com.example.cruddemo.CruddemoApplication
Creating new student object...
Saving Student Object...
2023-05-20T12:37:36.551+03:30 ERROR 9864 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:772) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at com.example.cruddemo.CruddemoApplication.main(CruddemoApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.cruddemo.entity.student
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:289) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:232) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at com.example.cruddemo.dao.StudentDAOImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.save(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.cruddemo.CruddemoApplication.createStudent(CruddemoApplication.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.cruddemo.CruddemoApplication.lambda$commandLineRunner$0(CruddemoApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.cruddemo.entity.student
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:737) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:721) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy80.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.cruddemo.dao.StudentDAOImpl.save(StudentDAOImpl.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 17 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

how can I solve it

Comment: if you have "Could not autowire. No beans of the 'EntityManager' type were found." you wouldn't get this problem. so which is it? problem saving or problem autowiring entitymanager?